# Running tcl Script from other directory while script refer to a local file

Tags: tcl, filepath

There are two or more scripts.
Script A

```
#Script A
setenv K1 V1
```

Script B

```
#Script B
source "script A"
# some code
```

When I run script B from its location its work fine.
But I need to run it from some other location like:
_> /some/other/location/ # tclsh pathtoscriptB/script.tcl

It giving error  
couldn't read file "script A": no such file or directory.

Note : Location of script can be changed according to user who use it.

Comment: Did you try something like `source "$pathtoscriptA/script.tcl"`?

Comment: We do not know at which path user store these scripts. We only know that both script are at same location ..

Comment: Then what about the path to scriptB?

Comment: lets Suppose Script stored at A/B/C/scriptB.tcl <br> But we may run it from path A/D/E/

Comment: Then scriptA will be in the same location according to your previous comment, right?

Comment: I mean, if you know the path to scriptB, you can get the path to scriptA, right?

Comment: yes Script A will be at A/B/C/scriptA.tcl

Comment: I want to know how to add path to source line because path of calling script B is changing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the technique given at the end of page http://wiki.tcl.tk/1384 - 
adapted for this case, script B would do:

```
source [file join [file dirname [info script]] "script A"]
```